# Can't load the jdbc driver class. ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, database, jsp, jdbc

I am using eclipse and have to develop a jsp application that connects to a derby db.
After I setup the database I went into my project and added derbyclient.jar as well as derbyclient.jar as reference.
However each time I try to get the jdbc class I am getting a ClassNotFoundException.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:674)
> org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:179)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

I have also tried it with a mysql database and got the same result so I thought maybe I did something wrong with the way I reference.
[image: References]
[image: project settings]

I intend to use a business java class which then will be used in jsp because I don't want to have the db access code in the jsp code.
The current "BusinessManager.java" class looks like this (only mocking stuff which needs to be replaced with database code).

```
    package com.forum.shared;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

public class BusinessManager {

    
    public List<ForumEntity> LoadFromDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");                  
          //java.sql.Connection connect = null;
          //String dbName = "D:/Apache/test/forum";
          //String connectionURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/" + dbName + ";create=true";

          //connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
          
          
        List<ForumEntity> result = new ArrayList<ForumEntity>();
        

        ForumEntity mockData = new ForumEntity();
        mockData.setID(1);
        mockData.setAntwortId(0);
        mockData.setAntwort(false);
        mockData.setInhalt("Willkommen im Forum!");
        mockData.setTitle("Willkommen");
        mockData.setName("Admin");
        mockData.setMail("admin@hszg.de");
        mockData.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
        
        ForumEntity answerData = new ForumEntity();
        answerData.setID(2);
        answerData.setAntwortId(1);
        answerData.setName("Max Mustermann");
        answerData.setMail("max_mustermann@gmx.com");
        answerData.setInhalt("Das ist eine Antwort");
        answerData.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
        mockData.addAnswer(answerData);
        
        result.add(mockData);
        return result;      
    }
    public ForumEntity LoadFromDatabaseById(int id)
    {
        ForumEntity result = new ForumEntity();
        
        result.setID(1);
        result.setAntwortId(0);
        result.setAntwort(false);
        result.setInhalt("Willkommen im Forum!");
        result.setTitle("Willkommen");
        result.setName("Admin");
        result.setMail("admin@hszg.de");
        result.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
        ForumEntity answerData = new ForumEntity();
        answerData.setID(2);
        answerData.setAntwortId(1);
        answerData.setName("Max Mustermann");
        answerData.setMail("max_mustermann@gmx.com");
        answerData.setInhalt("Das ist eine Antwort");
        answerData.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
        result.addAnswer(answerData);
        return result;      
    }
    
    public boolean CreateAndSafeForumEntity(int antwordId, boolean antwort, String titel, String inhalt, String name, String mail)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        
        
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

I am out of ideas. I have added the jar files for both dbms and non can be loaded. Any ideas?

**Edit: I used  this eclipse project template**
[image: project template]

**Edit: Update**
Now it gets intersting. I decided to try a different approach. I kept the libs as reference but decided to try load them during runtime.

```
    public List<ForumEntity> LoadFromDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    
    List<File> jars = Arrays.asList(new File("D:\\Apache\\db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin\\lib").listFiles());
    URL[] urls = new URL[jars.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jars.size(); i++) {
        try {
            urls[i] = jars.get(i).toURI().toURL();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    URLClassLoader childClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver", true , childClassLoader);

    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");                  
    //java.sql.Connection connect = null;
    //String dbName = "D:/Apache/test/forum";
    //String connectionURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/" + dbName + ";create=true";

    //connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
      
      
    List<ForumEntity> result = new ArrayList<ForumEntity>();
    

    ForumEntity mockData = new ForumEntity();
    mockData.setID(1);
    mockData.setAntwortId(0);
    mockData.setAntwort(false);
    mockData.setInhalt("Willkommen im Forum!");
    mockData.setTitle("Willkommen");
    mockData.setName("Admin");
    mockData.setMail("admin@hszg.de");
    mockData.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
    
    ForumEntity answerData = new ForumEntity();
    answerData.setID(2);
    answerData.setAntwortId(1);
    answerData.setName("Max Mustermann");
    answerData.setMail("max_mustermann@gmx.com");
    answerData.setInhalt("Das ist eine Antwort");
    answerData.setZeit(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()));
    mockData.addAnswer(answerData);
    
    result.add(mockData);
    return result;      
}
```

Guess what when I previously reached Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver") he allways threw the ClassNotFoundException. Now with the runtime library loading code above I don't get the ClassNotFoundException anymore when I execute Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"). Very weird. I must have done something wrong while I set the references.

Comment: Do you use maven or gradle?

Comment: One reason for this error message can be that the used jdbc driver is not compatible with your database version and or java version.

Comment: Have you installed the jdbc driver  for Derby?

Comment: @LevonMinasian Very good question. Where can I look that up? Sry but I normally don't use jsp or java. Haven't done java since 12 years. I just went into eclipse created a new project and selected Web=> Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: @Reporter The version of derby I am using requires java 9 or higher (derby v. 10.15.2.0). Should  What do you mean by installed the driver? Shouldn't it be enough to give him the path to the jdbc library?

Comment: @Dev86 According your posted pictures you have installed the jdbc driver for mysql not for derby

Comment: @Reporter check again pls. On the image you see both mysql. As well as derby.jar and derbyclient.jar After derby couldn't be loaded I tried it with mysql and got the same result. he can't load the jar files for some reason.

Comment: @dev86 A good sign for using maven as build tool is that a file called pomx.xml exists in your project. If not can you try to install the driver on your tomcat? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-build-forge/7.1.2?topic=components-apache-tomcat-installation-configuration gives an example how to install a jdbc driver for tomcat.

Comment: May alterantive link for another example is https://documentation.signavio.com/suite/de/Content/process-manager/adminguide/installation/install-jdbc-driver.htm

Comment: @Reporter I've updated the initial post. Very insteresting behavior. I decided that i will give it a try loading the libs during runtime with a directory path. Now I don't get any ClassNotFoundException at Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver", true , childClassLoader); But i would prefer not doing it that way. There must be an issue with the way I set the reference but I can't find the issue.